# Design specifications Venera 13/14

Tags: design, aerospace-engineering

I am trying to 3D model the [Venera 13 or Venera 14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venera_13) spacecraft. These are Russian spacecraft from the 1980s. I am looking for design specifications, plans, schematics, or anything else that might make this easier. I suppose if anything exists publicly it would be in Russian but that would be a place to start!

Comment: You might be more success by posting this on SE Space Exploration. A couple of Russian members there are good at tracking down things associated with Soviet & Russian space exploration matters.